# WLClient - Invoke adapter procedure for native iOS applications

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibm-mobilefirst, watchkit, worklight-adapters

I am trying to use Worklite to invoke adapter procedure in watch OS1 application. When I run it, getting the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WLClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in InterfaceController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you have added required frameworks to watchkit app target.The following libraries/frameworks are required to connect to worklight environment.

http://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/wp-content/uploads/sites/32/2014/12/link-binary.png

I  was able to call worklight adapter in my watchkit app.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Watch is not supported currently supported in Worklight/MobileFirst Platform Foundation.

Comment: Watch OS 2 is not supported. But I think watch OS 1 is supported.